# My where clause doesn't apply on my result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, count, group-by

I have this query

```
_ctx.TestPackageReportDetails.GroupBy(i => new {i.Status, i.TestPackageId})
                .Where(m => m.Count(i => i.Status == "Accept") == 5)
```

The result :

[image]

And this query :

```
  var q2 = _ctx.TestPackages.ToList();
```

[image]

Now  i create a join between two result :

```
 _ctx.TestPackageReportDetails.GroupBy(i => new { i.Status, i.TestPackageId })
                .Where(m => m.Count(i => i.Status == "Accept") == 5)
                .Join(_ctx.TestPackages, i => i.Key.TestPackageId, m => m.Id, (i, m) => new { pack = m, det = i })
                .Sum(i => i.pack.Size);
```

I create a joint based on `testpackageid` and i need the sum of size value with this condition  `Where(m => m.Count(i => i.Status == "Accept") == 5)`,but it doesn't work ,and the query calculates all package size not the package size with this condition `Where(m => m.Count(i => i.Status == "Accept") == 5)`

Comment: Could you also provide class of `_ctx` and sample data for testing?

Comment: How can the screenshot be showing the query results when the query only returns a single value which is the SUM ?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - The query given above does not apply on data that was removed by the `.Where`.

Comment: Only now I see that error in the picture. Please edit your question's name and content to match what is happening in the error

Comment: @GiladGreen i changed the post

Comment: @user3185569 is it clear?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter out the records with the status that you don't need. Also you need to start to make use of the Elegant Query-Syntax which is more readable. Like this:

```
var sum = (from i in _ctx.TestPackageReportDetails
           where i.Status == "Accept"
           group i by new { i.Status, i.TestPackageId } into grouping
           where grouping.Count() == 5
           join m in _ctx.TestPackages
           on grouping.Key.TestPackageId equals m.Id
           select m.Size).Sum();
```

Comment: @EhsanAkbar I really need to compare the generated SQL queries to know the exact difference. I can't do that because i don't have the database, but you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You´ve got a problem with either your connectionstring, your database or your code. The reason for this error when you remove *Sum()* is because after removing this the execute of this LINQ Statement is deferred when you first call a function that executes it. This could be a *foreach* or a *toList()* or something similar. In one of your calling methods EntityFramework internally opens another *DataReader* so if you want to solve this problem you should check up if your connectionstring has the *MultipleActiveResultSets* Option enabled.

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

If you enable this, you should be able to open multiple DataReaders at once.